# .htaccess redirects subdomain to top domain when it shouldn't

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

I'm running a web app in azure and I can only use .htaccess to achieve the behaviour I'm looking for: if the requested URL doesn't match a file under `/app` or `/dist` folder then redirect the request to `/dist/main.php`. This works well if I try something like: `http://example.com/` (the request goes into /dist/main.php without any URL redirect) but if I instead use `http://www.example.com` then it returns a 301 to `http://example.com/dist/main.php` and I have no idea why?

.htaccess content under wwwroot:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     Options +FollowSymLinks

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dist%{REQUEST_URI} -f
     RewriteRule .* dist/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app%{REQUEST_URI} -f
     RewriteRule .* app/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                
     RewriteRule .* /dist/main.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I also tried the last line as: `RewriteRule ^ /dist/main.php [L,QSA]`

Comment: There is no `301` redirect rule shown here. It might be in Apache config or in your code.

Comment: The first line I have on my main.php is an echo to debug and then die;

Comment: Do you have any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path? ie. `/dist/.htaccess`?

Comment: Dear @MrWhite ... that was exactly the issue, someone without my knowledge added one when they shouldn't have and "ls" wasn't showing it (wasn't using -la) ... thanks